# how do I use Count to find brands in each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where all the columns have data type VARCHAR(MAX).

Is it possible to analyse data where I have date and brands, group it, remove duplicates then use count to find what how many brands found for each month.

To give you simple visual explanation (real data is massive)...

```
Date               Brand
2012-11-12T16:30   SamSung   
2012-16-11T12:20   Sony
2012-16-12T09:30   Samsung
2012-16-11T10:00   Sony
```

Output  I would like to see

```
Date      Brand     TotalCount
12-2012   Samsung   2 
11-2012   Sony      2
```

I tried to use the following it takes ages then I didn't know to combine the count. I know how to use Count with group(s) but I am not sure if Group By should be used.

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(8), SomeDate, 4),Brand from SomeTable group by   
SomeDate, Brand
```

Then I tried the following but I don't know how combine Brand and use Count...

```
SELECT monthYear FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT DATENAME(month,SomeDate) + ' ' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(year,SomeDate)) monthYear, 
CONVERT(varchar(8),SomeDate, 4) orderCol
FROM SomeTable) A
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,orderCol) desc
```

and I am getting an error and I believe it's because there are T's in the SomeDate column...

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2012-11-16' to data type int
```

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Thanks if anyone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know storing data in `varchar(max)` isn't really a good idea.  You should use the built-in data types, particularly for numbers and dates.

In any case, the month is just the left 7 characters of the date column, so:

```
select left(somedate, 7) as yyyymm, brand, count(*)
from someTable
group by left(somedate, 7), brand;
```

Comment: thank you. I had raw data so at the time I didn't know what exactly data I had  so I just did investigation on the net to find a best possible solution.

Comment: @DiscoDude . . . That is actually a very good reason for having the columns be strings.

Comment: It is odd that a correct, accepted answer attracts anonymous down votes.

Comment: Is that why it takes long time to extract the data? I will keep in mind the next time in regards to column strings.

Comment: This query would not be faster (noticeably) with the right data types, because it is scanning the entire table.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with @Gordon that you have to always use specific data type to store data and specially for date because it behave differently by culture

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        LEFT(Date,4) AS 'Year', 
        LEFT(REPLACE(Date,LEFT(Date,8),''),2) AS 'Month',
        Brand
    FROM @tblTest
)
SELECT
    T.[Month]+'-'+T.[Year] AS 'Date',
    T.Brand,
    COUNT(Brand) AS TotalCount
FROM T
GROUP BY T.Brand,T.[Year],T.[Month]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sandip Patel.

Answer (score 1):

Try below very simple query to fetch result you require.

```
select 
    convert(varchar,DATEPART(m,date))+'-'+convert(varchar,DATEPART(yyyy,date))  as [Date],Brand,count(brand) as Total
from temp
group by brand,DATEPART(m,date),DATEPART(yyyy,date)
```